# Что изучить для начинающего разработчика мобильных приложений

Tags: android, react-native, мобильная-разработка

Я начинающий в разработке мобильных приложений. Только вот не знаю что начать изучать: **ReactNative** или **нативные приложения**. Хотелось бы узнать какой из вариантов  лучше и какой будет актуален для инди разработчика приложений.

**Спасибо за отклик**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваш вопрос не совсем корректен.

Не пытайтесь изучить за 5 мин разделы на которые люди тратят годы.

Попробуйте начать с простых приложений для Android, заодно подучите Java.

Во время обучения уделите внимание архитектуре, а также, спустя пару лет, потихоньку определитесь - какой берег ближе вашему сердцу.

Спустя **годы** сбрейте бороду и вернитесь сюда, чтобы указать путь другому человеку, не могущему определиться)

И этой оперы:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]